# How to create an arbitrary number of variables inside a MATLAB function

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cells

In MATLAB, I have a function in which the number of variables inside varies. This is best explained with the example shown bellow.

I have a function:

Sometimes there are three input arguments and the code looks like this:

```
function [Y] = ffwd(X,W1,W2)

A1 = sigmf(W1*X, [1,0]);

Y = sigmf(W2*A1, [1,0]);
```

Sometimes there are four input arguments and the code looks like this:

```
function [Y] = ffwd(X,W1,W2,W3)

A1 = sigmf(W1*X, [1,0])

A2 = sigmf(W2*A1, [1,0])

Y = sigmf(W3*A2, [1,0])
```

Sometimes there are five input arguments and the code looks like this:

```
function [Y] = ffwd(X,W1,W2,W3,W4)

A1 = sigmf(W1*X, [1,0])

A2 = sigmf(W2*A1, [1,0])

A3 = sigmf(W3*A2, [1,0])

Y = sigmf(W4*A3, [1,0])
```

X, Y, W1, W2, W3 and so on..., are all matrices.

I need one function that will do the job of all of these, and work for any number of W's. I have tried to use the `cell(dim)` function to create (dim) number of variables, but it doesn't work.

This is what I have so far:

```
function [Y] = ffwd(X,Wcell)                  %Wcell is a cell of multiple matrices

S = size(Wcell,2);                            %this is the number of W's

A =cell(S-2,1);                               %This will create A1, A2, A3 etc

A(1) = sigmf(Wcell(1)*X, [1,0]);              %This calculates the first intermediate step  

for i=2:S-1

    A(i) = sigmf(Wcell(i)*A(i-1), [1,0]);     %This calculates all the middle intermediate steps
end

Y = sigmf(Wcell(S)*A(S-1), [1,0]);            %This calculates the last step
```

But it comes up with an error:

```
Undefined function 'mtimes' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in test (line 7)
A(1) = sigmf(Wcell(1)*X, [1,0]);
```

`Wcell(1)` is a matrix, because it is the first entry in `Wcell` which is a cell. `X` is also a matrix so I do not know why this doesn't work.

I have also tried to use `double(Wcell(1))`, but it comes up with the error

Conversion to double from cell is not possible

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Think you need VARARGIN - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html

Comment: No, `Wcell(1)` is a 1x1 cell array. `Wcell{1}` is a matrix. Anyway, unless cell arrays make sense for the rest of the code too, varargs is a far better approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is fundamentally on-track, but you have the cell array syntax incorrect and it seems unnecessarily complex. Using [`varargin`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) makes things even simpler since you can then simply call with the matrices as regular arguments rather than having to construct the cell array manually:

```
function [Y] = ffwd(X, varargin)
Y = X;
for ii=1:length(varargin)
    Y = sigmf(varargin{ii}*Y, [1,0]);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a simple case where X, W1, W2, etc are scalars, one can use this function -

```
function [Y] = ffwd(varargin)

IN = cell2mat(varargin{:});

Y = IN(1);
for k = 2:numel(IN)
    Y = sigmf(IN(k)*Y, [1,0]);
end

return;
```

The calling function/script would look like this -

```
X = 2;
IN = {[X 101 102 103 104]};
out = ffwd(IN)
```